# Unable to rename SCCM asset

Tags: sccm, rename

Simply put, I delete the asset from SCCM but when I go to reimage the machine I cannot rename. After I choose the image the task sequence begins without prompting for a machine name. What am I missing here?

Update:

This problem was attributed to a specific computer that was causing any computer that was being reimaged to take its name. We attributed it to a scanner driver on the said problem child.

I have a new problem now so I will make a new thread.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SCCM does not prompt for computer names during an OSD by default. There are 2 ways you can achieve this:

First, You can include a script in your task sequence that prompts for the computer name. An example of this is:

http://www.scconfigmgr.com/2013/10/02/prompt-for-computer-name-during-osd-with-powershell/

The second way is to set a Collection Variable on the All Unknown Computers collection. The computer should fall into this collection as you've deleted it out of SCCM. The variable needs to be configured as below:

- Name - OSDComputerName
- Uncheck "Do not display this value......."
- Value - leave blank

If you do a search for OSDComputerName you'll find quite a lot of information out there about it.

Hope this helps